# Use JSON result when ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have this code:

```
function openIzmeni(value) {
$.ajax({
            url: "getRzaizmenu.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true, 
            data: { vrednostid:value}, //your form data to post goes here as a json object
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {  
            console.log(data);
            $('#brojracuna1').val(data[0].br);
            console.log(data[0].br);
            console.log(data.br);
```

so as you can see I call getRzaizmenu.php to get JSON output.
getRzaizmenu.php code is:

```
try {


     $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM racuni WHERE ID=:id AND user_id=:user_id");
     $result->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['vrednostid'], ':user_id' => $user_id));
    $result = $result->fetchAll(); 

     $r= json_encode($result);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
     echo $r;
```

and this php return me output:

```
[{"ID":"22","0":"22","prefiks":"","1":"","br":"14321","2":"14321","sufiks":"993.67","3":"993.67","kupac":"Pavle Aleksov","4":"Pavle Aleksov","adresa":"Desanka Maksimovic 6\/a","5":"Desanka Maksimovic 6\/a","grad":"18320 Dimitrovgrad","6":"18320 Dimitrovgrad","pib":"567890","7":"567890","total":"1200.00","8":"1200.00","valuta":"Din","9":"Din","nacin":"gotovinsko","10":"gotovinsko","datum":"2015-05-25","11":"2015-05-25","rok":"2015-05-25","12":"2015-05-25","isporuka":"2015-05-25","13":"2015-05-25","naplaceno":"0000-00-00","14":"0000-00-00","napomene":"","15":"","interne":"","16":"","jezik":"","17":"","status":"","18":"","sifra":"yyx5y","19":"yyx5y","user_id":"1","20":"1"}]
```

So this code return me `"0":22` and `"ID":22` but its the same column.

and you can see I try to use this data into ajax success function like this:

```
success: function(data) {  
                console.log(data);
                $('#brojracuna1').val(data[0].br);
                console.log(data[0].br);
                console.log(data.br);
```

but I get undefined.

How I can use `data` in success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
dataType: "html",
```

to

```
dataType: "json",
```

And try again.

Comment: thats ok but why I get doube data from php:  "0":22 and "ID":22

Comment: Make one more change: `$result = $result->fetchAll()` to `$result = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Answer (score 1):

you have encoded the data, that's ok.
But while parsing you are not decoding the data. So you have to decode the data using JSON.parse() and parse function.

Comment: thats ok but why I get doube data from php:  "0":22 and "ID":22

Comment: `json_decode()` is PHP and the `undefined` error here is on the javascript side.

Comment: We can use JSON.parse(text[, reviver]) for javascript. thanks peter for notice

Comment: True, but the problem here is actually the `dataType: 'html'` part, which breaks jQuery's automatic parsing. (If the automatic parsing doesn't happen because the server sends the wrong content-type header for some reason, `dataType: 'json'` is the correct solution.)

Comment: Removed my -1 now as your solution is now correct if not optimal.

Comment: Thaks peter, i am very glad.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON, try like this

```
success: function(data) {  
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        console.log(index);
        console.log(element);
    });
});
```

Comment: thats ok but why I get doube data from php:  "0":22 and "ID":22

Comment: You don't parse the JSON here, you iterate over it. The problem is that `data` is a string in this case so your approach wouldn't work either.